# Why can't C++ infer the template type?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Why can't the compiler figure out these template parameters? Is there a way to make it do so?

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010.)

```
template<typename T, typename TFunc>
void call(TFunc func) { func(T()); }

void myfunc(void *) { }

int main() { call(myfunc); }
```

Comment: What do you expect the compiler to "figure out" the template parameters to be?

Comment: @James: `void *` and `void (*)(void *)` maybe?

Comment: "Why"? How could anyone possibly expect the compiler to figure out `T` in this case? What logic can the compiler possibly follow for deducing `T`???

Comment: It doesn't even match; `myfunc` accepts a `void*`, and you're trying to call it with no arguments.

Comment: @AndreyT- A very reasonable idea would be that it could look at the fact that the argument is a function type taking some type, then assign `T` to that.  It's not a *correct* idea, but for someone who isn't a wizard at templates it seems like a natural thought.

Comment: @AndreyT: I don't think my expectation was *that* weird...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`T` appears nowhere in the parameter list so `T` cannot be deduced from the function arguments.  All types to be deduced must appear in deduced contexts in the parameter list.  For example,

```
template <typename TReturn, typename TParameter>
void call(TReturn (*f)(TParameter))
{
    f(TParameter());
}
```

Comment: -1: no one said it has to be a function... (it could be a functor -- that's why I actually templated it in the first place)

Comment: @Mehrdad:  It's a good thing you said that in your question.  Oh wait, you didn't.  You asked "Why can't the compiler figure out these template parameters? Is there a way to make it do so?" and I answered that very question.  If you aren't happy with the answer to your question, perhaps you asked the wrong question.

Comment: @Kerrek:  Oops; no, either the `return` needs to go or the return type of `call` should be `TReturn`; I've removed the `return`, thank you.

Comment: @James: Changing my -1 to +1 because I misread your answer: I didn't realize that the code was an example for *your* explanation, rather than a solution for my own code in the question. Sorry about that! :(

Comment: Besides - `TFunc` can't be a functor. Unlike functions, functors can have more than one `operator()` which in turn means that `T` is ambiguous. (You've got similar but different issues with overloaded functions; in that case `&myfunc` already is ambiguous)

Comment: Please keep comments constructive and on topic. I've removed several under this answer because they degenerated into noise.

Answer (score 3):

Template parameter deduction for function templates only works based on function arguments, nothing else. The function definition is never looked at for the purpose of determining the template parameters, so your parameter `T` cannot possibly be deduced.

You could remedy your situation by incorporating the type into the function signature: Since you expect the outer function to be called with a function itself, make that explicit:

```
template <typename T> void foo(void(*f)(T))
{
  T x;
  f(x);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Which function are you talkin about when you say "only works based on function arguments"

Comment: @Seth: I'm referring to the arguments of the function template.

Comment: "*You could remedy your situation by making the function signature a `std::function<void(T)>`*" How would this help the compiler deduce `T` when a function pointer is passed as the argument?

Comment: @Ildjarn: `template <typename T> void foo(std::function<void(T)> f);`. Just like James's answer, just with fewer asterisks.

Comment: @Kerrek : When passing a plain function pointer, you think that will compile? [:-/](http://ideone.com/cBTWF)

Comment: @Kerrek:  That won't work:  among other problems, `std::function<T>` has a constructor template that takes any type `U`.  You would need to explicitly construct a `std::function<void(T)>` and pass that to the function template.

Comment: Yeah, I see. In that case one should probably provide another overload for function pointers that calls the `std::function` version, just to be general.

Comment: @Kerrek : It wouldn't work for functors either, or for anything other than an actual `std::function<>` for that matter. I.e., `std::function<>` is not capable of helping template argument deduction in this scenario.

Comment: @Ildjarn: Right, I see. Lambdas come to mind as a useful application, I suppose, but it's an interesting question if you could make something that captures all callable types. Perhaps a typetrait?

Comment: @Kerrek : If it was the return type in question, type traits would help; for argument types, it's not possible because of the existence of polymorphic functors.

Comment: @Ildjarn: I was thinking of a typetrait that checks for the existing of an `operator()` member, followed by another one that checks if the member has the correct signature. Not entirely sure if you can test for the existence of operators, but I have a hunch that it can be done.

Comment: @Kerrek : Yes, I think checking for `operator()` with specific type arguments is feasible, but it would rule out the ability to pass functors/functions with defaulted arguments, as well as functors/functions with _convertible_ types (as opposed to exactly-matching types), which is not unheard of.

Comment: @Ildjarn: Well, then we're back to making a typetrait that only checks if a certain *expression* is valid, which may include conversions and default arguments. Now I'm not so sure how to do that, though, something with `declval`...

Comment: @Kerrek : That assumes the question is tagged c++0x/c++11. ;-] But we digress -- the point is that `std::function<>` cannot help with template argument deduction here, and consequently does not help your answer, and I'd like to remove my -1 before I go to sleep. ;-D

Comment: @Ildjarn: Likewise (3h past my projected bedtime, but I capped early!), and thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 2):

Combine function overloading with functors, and it becomes impossible in the general case to determine what arguments can be passed to a callable entity.

Consider, for example

```
struct FunctorExample {
    void operator()(int x) {...}
    std::string operator()(const std::string& ) {...}
};
```

If there were some way to coax the compiler to pattern match on arguments, it would have to have undefined or error behavior when applied to `FunctorExample`.

Instead, the trend seems to be that when you want to template metaprogram with functors, you specify the functor and argument list.  Examples (off the top of my head) being `boost::result_of` and `boost::fusion`.

**Edit**: That said, if you're willing to restrict your attention somewhat, and you can use some C++11 syntax (`decltype`), you can arrange to introspect a bit more:

```
// Support functors with a very simple operator():
template <typename T> struct argument :
    public argument<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

// Pointers to member functions
template <typename C, typename R, typename A> struct argument<R(C::*)(A)>
    {typedef A type;};

// Function types
template <typename R, typename A> struct argument<R(A)> {typedef A type;};

// Function pointer types.
template <typename R, typename A> struct argument<R(*)(A)> {typedef A type;};

// Now for call:
template <typename FuncType>
void call(FuncType func) { 
    typedef typename argument<FuncType>::type Arg;
    func(Arg());
}

// example:
class FunctorInt {public: int operator()(int ) {return 0;};};
void myfunc(void *) {}

int main() {
    call(myfunc);
    call(FunctorInt());
}
```

Variadic templates could be used to expand this stuff to support more than one argument.

Comment: Forgot to mention: VC++10 supports this use of decltype(), as does gcc 4.5 (with `--std=c++0x`).  Oddly, VC++10 threw fits when I tried to use a typedef in the main definition of `argument` instead of using inheritance...